# Check if database connection alive

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm writing stock quotes processing engine and receiving async notifications from postgresql database with pgjdbc-ng-0.6 library. I'd like to know if my database connection is still alive, so I wrote in thread's `run()` method

```
    while (this.running) {
        try {
            this.running = pgConnection.isValid(Database.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
            gracefullShutdown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            gracefullShutdown();
        }
    }
```

I read `isValid()` declaration and it stated that the function will return `false` if timeout reached. However, `isValid()` just hangs indefinitely and `run()` is never exited. To create connectivity issues I disable VPN my application uses to connect to database. Rather rude way,but function must return false... Is this bug in driver or another method exists?
I tried `setNetworkTimeout()` in `PGDataSource`, but without any success.

Comment: You could try to execute some query and check whether it returns normally or whether some exception is thrown.

Comment: That method doesn't give me predictable amount of time problems are detected. Probably, the solution is to use Executors from concurrent package and query Future with needed timeout. Looks like reinventing the wheel though.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible handlings of this problem for Enterprise developers is to use existing threadPool to create a separate thread for submitting in
Callable with test `call()` for DB (in case of Oracle it may be `"SELECT 'OK'  FROM dual"`),
using statement `object.execute('...')`, (not `executeUpdate`, because it
may cause the call to get stuck), and further using for example - `future.get(3, TimeUnit.Seconds)`.

Using this approach in a final call you need to catch `InterruptedException`
for `get()` call. If Callable throws you set database availability as false, if not then true.

Before using this approach inside the Enterprise application you have to ensure you have access to application server threadPool executor in certain object and @Autowire it there.

Comment: `from dual` would be invalid in Postgres (unless you create a table named `dual`)